# Programmatic/dynamic way to get all rules

Tags: stylelint

Is there any way to access all existing rules of stylelint in a programatic way? For example some jsons I can parse or a method I can invoke?

For instance the method through which the documentation files are created, if they are made automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to access all existing rules of stylelint in a programatic way?

Yes, all of the built-in rule functions are available as part of the API at [`stylelint.rules`](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/developer-guide/plugins.md#stylelintrules).

> For instance the method through which the documentation files are created, if they are made automatically?

The [list of rules](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/blob/master/docs/user-guide/rules.md) within the documentation is not automatically made. It is manually edited.